# Package projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Lets say I have n projects in eclipse and they are only conceptually connected.

How to add every one of these projects as a package in a new umbrella project?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse you can hook projects together using the Project tab in your build path configuration dialog:

- right-click on your higher-order project
- select Build Path
- select Configure Build Path...
- select the Projects tab and add the other projects as references

You might also look into [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) as a build management system, which would allow you to create consumable libraries.  Each of your projects would use Maven to generate a JAR artifact, and your umbrella project would use Maven to reference them as dependencies.  I believe [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) would also help you in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

In order to logically combine the elements (in this case, projects) together, you can create a "Working Set" in Eclipse. There can be different type of working set.

Here are steps to create a Java working set (as the question is tagged as Java):

1. File - New - Others..
2. Select "Java Working Set" under Java.
3. Select the project you want to add into the working set and give a

Once the working set is created, you can use it at many place in eclipse. Personally I use them a lot in search to narrow the search results and on Package/Project Explorer to see only the projects I am interested in at the moment.

To emphasize that the Java working sets are just logical grouping of the projects, here are couple of examples.

- Working sets "Batch Projects" and "Web Projects" based on type.
- Working sets "SVN Projects" and "CVS Projects" based on the source repository.

Read more on the [offical](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm) eclipse documentation.